# Problems accessing WCF service via the web

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

Thanks to stackoverflow (mostly), I have created a WCF service that is able to pull data from our ms sql database and relay it back in a json format. The service works as expected locally and on its home server within our network. However, I can't seem to access the service when outside the network.

Are there additional parameters needed in the code to accommodate being published over the web or is it possibly just a host setup and has nothing to do with WCF or the service?

The server is 2008 R2 & IIS 7.5 which is currently hosting a dozen or so of our websites.  We have setup a port for the service as well.

This is the web.config file I am using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SrvcBehavior" name="Service.svc">
        <endpoint address="JSON" behaviorConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="RESTEP" contract="Service.Isvc" />
        <endpoint address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Basic" contract="Service.Isvc" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JSONEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SrvcBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="server=SERVER-DATABASE\SQL2005;database=myDatabase;uid=USERID;password=USERPASSWORD;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you set up on a different port than 80?  Your config file looks fine.  Also, I would not broadcast metadata when it is open to the world...

Comment: Is there any type of authentication set up on your sites?  SSL? Certficate requirements, even on other pages?

Comment: Set up on port 8085 and is tested to work throughout the internal network on that port.  Port 80 is allowed as well.  I'm sure there is minor authentication on the other pages, but I'm unsure exactly what they may be.

Comment: Sounds like your entire site might have some type of auth on it that flows down to your WCF.  If you are internal, on a domain, it might actually have Windows Auth by default.  I would go into the IIS settings for the applicaiton and just double check everything, because I don't believe it is with your service.  Your firewall is allowing incoming for 8085 too?